# C++ sorting function for scheduling program

Tags: c++, sorting, scheduling

I have an assignment where I am given a list of events with a start time and end time and I need to make it schedule as many events as possible for that day assuming there is only one room to use. So the events are sorted by end time. The sorting algorithm I am supposed to implement is as follows:

sort() — a function to sort a floats array data[], creating an array of sorted indices. The sort() function does not sort the data, but fills the the array indx[] so that
   data[indx[0]], data[indx[1]], ..., data[indx[NUM_EVENTS - 1]]
are the values of data[] in ascending order.

I am a little bit confused on what exactly it is asking but anyways this is what I have so far:

```
void sort(float data[], int indx[], int len){
  int temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++){

      if (data[j] > data[j+1]){
        temp = data[j];
        indx[j] = data[j+1];
        indx[j+1] = temp;

      }
    }
  }
}
```

This code compiles but doesnt behave as it should. When I try to print what is in indx[] I get strange results. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you cross check that the elements in the array `indx` are in range [0, `NUM_EVENTS`-1] ? Probably, it's the problem.

Comment: Yes I dont think thats an issue

Comment: Ok, I am looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading uninitialized memory. You are copying elements from `data` to `indx`, but only when `data[j] > data[j + 1]`. When that isn't true twice in a row, you have an element of `indx` that isn't assigned a value. It has an indeterminate value of random bits left by whatever used the memory before, and reading it is undefined behavior.

Comment: so do I fix this just by adding an else?

Comment: @MatthewHanson Well, technically your solution would be to do the assignment correctly. You need to fill `indx` so that it holds the indices of elements of `data` in ascending order. `data[indx[0]]` should be the smallest element in `data`. This would mean every element in `indx` would be set, and you wouldn't have this problem.